# j2store add to cart widgetkit

Tags: joomla-3.x, view, layout, j2store

I'm trying to add J2Store cart to widgetkit grid stack layout with the following code in my **administrator/components/com_widgetkit/plugins/widgets/grid-stack/views/widget.php** file.

[image]

```
require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/helpers/j2store.php');

$product = F0FTable::getAnInstance('Product', 'J2StoreTable')->getClone();

if ($product->get_product_by_source('com_content', $item->id)) {
    echo $product->get_product_html();
}
```

The above code will not display the cart, but when I put above code inside of my **administrator/components/com_widgetkit/plugins/content/joomla/plugin.php** file it works...

[image]

...but the cart button is positioned above all content.

What do I do to display the cart via my **administrator/components/com_widgetkit/plugins/widgets/grid-stack/views/widget.php** file?